# A registration already exists for URI - How to programmatically check / remove registration?

Tags: http, wcf, uri, azure-service-fabric, wcf-binding

I am hosting my WCF services in service fabric. One of the WCF service starts a `HttpSelfHostServer` on a port after startup. I sometimes gets the error:

> A registration already exists for URI 'http://localhost:10503/'.
>      at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.EndOpen(IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.Web.Http.SelfHost.HttpSelfHostServer.OpenListenerComplete(IAsyncResult result)

In service fabric, I think there could be multiple services spun up by the framework. I am wondering if there is any way to programmatically check the port and detect there is a service registered with it and remove it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/show-urlacl
Netsh http show Urlacl command is able to help us to detect the reserved URl. But as you know, we need to elevate the permission to an administrator, then delete or add the entry for the specifical users and accounts(The administrator account can directly remove the occupation and use the reserved URL).

```
Netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user 
delete urlacl url=https://+:80/MyUri
```

If it is accomplished programmatically, we need to execute the delete command as an administrator, who can directly remove the occupation and use the reserved URL. Therefore, I don't think it is feasible.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hi Abraham, Thanks for your reply! The url is stored in app.config file. I wrote a bit of code to access the config file before the service is loaded and programmatically adds a virtual directory path like http://localhost:10503/some-guid. It seems to work for a while, however, I still get the error some times. I am still stuck!

Comment: If you have any solution to this please let me know

Comment: Will it be because when you close and open the service, it does not properly close and release the previous port occupation?
I suggest you add IF statement to detect the service host working state during the Service_Open event and Service_closed event.

Comment: I have no control over the source code. The service fabric service are wrappers around the wcf services (which i can't change)